# Extend Rainlab Static Pages with image field

Tags: octobercms

I want to add an extra image field in October CMS plugin 'Static Pages'. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

A better answer would be to use the [documentation for the plugin itself](http://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-pages) which talks about adding custom variables (fields) to pages via layouts. As an example, say you had layout default.htm:

```
description = "Default Layout with Image field"
[staticPages]
==
{variable name="banner" label="Banner" tab="Header" type="mediafinder" mode="image"}{/variable}

<img src="{{ banner | media }}" alt="" />
{{ page }}
```

The `{variable}{/variable}` tags can be used to define extra fields to be displayed in the backend for pages that utilize the layout that defines those variables. You can use pretty much any built in October field types as the `type` of the variable, and then you access the set value by accessing it via Twig: `{{ nameOfVariable }}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the plugin. You can find how to do it in the [official documentation.](https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/extending)